# Facebook Unity SDK hangs on Login() on iOS if you deny apps permissions

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I've been struggling for a couple of hours with a strange bug in Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.3 Beta and Unity 4.3.4

After calling FB.Login, the onInitDelegate will not be called due to an Exception thrown by MiniJSON on iOSFacebook.cs line 356. The msg parameter is actually an empty string and this is why MiniJSON fails to parse as JSON

The workaround I found is to add a try/catch block around the parse

```
public void OnLogin(string msg)    
{
    try
    {
        var parameters = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(msg);

        if (parameters.ContainsKey ("user_id"))
        {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        //pull userId, access token and expiration time out of the response
        ParseLoginDict (parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FbDebug.Error("Could not parse Json string received. Got the following error: [" + e.GetType().Name + "] " + e.Message + "\n" + "Json string: " + msg, LoggerTags.CONNECTION);
    }

    OnAuthResponse(new FBResult(msg));
}
```

First of all, I am not sure why the response is an empty string, so maybe you could help me find out
Secondly, I hope that this will get fixed really soon

Answer (score 1):

This bug should have been fixed in the 5.0.3.  It's possible that IOSFacebook.cs didn't probably get overwritten when you copied the package over.

The unity SDK is a wrapper around our other SDKs (JS, Android and iOS).  Sometimes the underlying ones have small differences between them.  This is one of them and we do our best to address the difference and make them the same for Unity developers such as yourself.